# How to get the path of a drawable or ".gif" in android

Tags: html, android, image

I am trying to pass a HTML string to webview as following

`String data =  "<html>" +
"<body bgcolor=\"white \" align=\"center \" valign=\"center \">" +
"<table width=\"470\" height=\"725 \" >" +
"<tr>" +
"<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\">" +
"<font color=\"gray\">" +
getResources().getString(R.string.loading) + //this is the string i want to localize
"</font>" +

"<br/>" +
"<br/>" +
"<br/>" +
"<br/>" +
"<br/>" +
"<img src=\"" +
"loading.gif" + //this the GIF i want to pass
"\">" +
"</td>" + 
"</tr>" +
"</table>" +
"</body>" +
"</html>";
webview.loadData(data, "text/html", "UTF-8");`

All works fine but that gif is not getting loaded.
Only reason for passing html is to localize that string "loading".Earlier It was in assets and the string "Loading" was hard coded in html file. now I am passing it by getting getting string resources (getResources().getString(R.string.loading)). Problem is passing "GIF".

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to your problem is, save all this HTML code in to a file and put that file in the asset folder along with the image (gif) file. Then simply load that HTML file in the WebView. If you want to add any runtime values in the HTML, then add some placeholder strings into your HTML, and replace them at runtime with String.format(). In this way, you have to use the loadDataWithBaseURL() method to show the contents.

Comment: Thank you and Sorry, i am little confused about using String.format() to replace the placeholder in HTML;

Comment: How to use String.format() to replace the place holder in html. And what would be the placeholder in html?

Comment: I got it done.. i passed a string with whatever the content of html as data to "loadDataWithBaseURL" and gave the base url as "file:///android_asset/". automatically it searches for GIF in assets.

Comment: Yes, i've done it. Just your hint to use loadDataWithBaseURL() took me to solution :)